# Is there a way to replace the load method in an objective c class with a stub method in a mach-o binary?

Tags: mach-o

I am learning about parsing and editing mach-o files and I am stuck on particular issue.

I am able to read the segments and sections within a binary which is a test iOS app written in Objective-C. I am looking for a way to replace the load method in a class with a stub method e.g my_load in another class within the same binary. Is there a way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's very possible. Check the awesome tool - LIEF